# Capturing the "original" return value from with-out-str

Tags: clojure

I'm using with-out-str to capture some data that is printed to stdout.  Problem is that with-out-str seems to throw away the return value from my function.  Is there any way I can capture both?  I'd like to have my cake and eat it too.

Example:

```
(with-out-str (do (prn "test") (+ 1 1)))
```

Comment: Which return value are you referring to? The `2` returned from evaluating `(+ 1 1)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aping the definition of the core library's [`with-out-str`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-out-str) macro, you could define a similar one like this:

```
(defmacro with-out-str-and-value
  [& body]
  `(let [s# (new java.io.StringWriter)]
     (binding [*out* s#]
       (let [v# ~@body]
         (vector (str s#)
                 v#)))))
```

Without [the `values` function from Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_values.htm) and its [multiple function return values](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/26_glo_m.htm#multiple_values), here we return a vector instead; the first item is the text collected from *standard output*, and the second item is the value returned by evaluating the body form.